# How I can set a column value for all my rows that already exist in the database with some sort of mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I want to set the value of the column 'character_hold' to 'no' for all my rows in my MYSQL database. Is there a SQL statement I can use in phpmyadmin to set them all to 'no'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE tableName set character_hold='no'